# Polling network range for certain SNMP OIDs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, networking, scripting

Shell script scan network range for specific SNMP OIDs:

```
#!/bin/bash

# snmpget command poll the network range for certain OIDs

for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do 
    host=10.77.32.$i; 
    snmpget -v 2c -c public -t 0.5 -r 1 $host iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2 iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.16; 
done;
read -p 'press Enter to continue...'
```

Is it possible slightly modify script for two options:

1. to extend the range of polls: 10.77.x.x
2. only print OID that have target MAC address, skip the other MACs.

i.e. network range need be polled for specific OIDs, it target MAC present in that OID, it should be printed. The other MAC adresses is skipped - even if certain OIDs present, but contains no target MAC address, it will not printed:

```
...
Timeout: No Response from 10.77.32.242.
Timeout: No Response from 10.77.32.241.
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1 = Hex-STRING: 00 09 4B EF D2 02 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2 = Hex-STRING: E4 46 C5 B7 93 14 
Timeout: No Response from 10.77.32.239.
Timeout: No Response from 10.77.32.238.
...
```

Is 2nd option is difficult, it would be enough to extend range.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "only print OID that have target MAC address, skip the other MACs."? Can you post an example sketch of the output you would like?

Comment: The output of existing script already posted in topic. If specific OID found in the some IP address, script print corresponding value in the output. If not such OID object present in the IP address , script print "Timeout: No Response.." I mean can the script print MAC only if it found the target MAC address, instead of all MAC addresses found.

Comment: Why minus? Question is very clear, and complies with topic rules and guidelines.

Comment: Seems like you could just add another `for` loop for the 3rd octet, and then use `grep` to look for your mac addresses.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, using `grep` will be best option for this. Can you show how should look this additional `for` loop for 3rd octet?